# Clipping multiple raster layers in R using a shape file

Tags: r, raster, clip

I'm very new to R and still trying to figure out how it works.

I have climate data I converted from netCDF to raster images, and there are a lot of files. The whole data is for Africa but I 'm only interested in data for Johannesburg. I now need to clip these (thousands|) raster files  and I have some shape filed I can use. Suppose my files are saved in D: folder named: `Climate` and file named: `temperature`, may you please assist on how I can clip this in R?

Comment: Can you give some code to display what you tried to help solve your problem?

Comment: You can use `for`loop, `apply` or `map` functions, but without code we can't help you

Comment: Take a look at `?gdalUtils::gdalwarp`